# How do I improve my code for better/faster performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this INSERT setup where I want the following to be filtered and inserted in a table. The '*Splitout*' has more than 30000000 rows. This statement is taking more than 2 hours for a single project I have 100 projects like this. 
My initial plan was to insert everything at once but because it took more than 20 for it to execute I had to split by projects but even then the performance was very low. I was planning on using CROSS-APPLY but wasn't really sure how it would apply in my case. Any suggestions to improve the performance is appreciated. 
Below is the code I have now -  Thank you !

```
insert into DimQuestion (ResponderKey, ProjectID, qid, Question, QuestionType,AttributeID,                                                                            
Attribute, ProductID, ProductCode, ProductName, AnswerCode, AnswerLabel)


SELECT  distinct  RKey
             ,a.ProID
             ,a.qid
             ,c.QID + ' - ' + c.[Ql] as Question
             ,c.[Type] as QType
             ,a.AttributeID
             ,e.Attribute
             ,a.ProductID
             ,d.ProductCode
             ,d.ProductName
             ,a.Answers
             ,'AnswerLabel' = case when a.qid not in ('Q2','QA','QA1','QA2','QA5','QA6','QA7','QA8','QF1','QF2','QF2c','QF2a','QF5',
                                                                                       'QF6','QF7','QF8','QF9','QF10','QX5','QX12') 
                                                                                        then datamap.[Answer Label]
                                   when a.qid = 'Q2' 
                                                                                        then f.AnswerLabel
                                                             when a.qid in ('QA','QA1','QA2','QA5','QA6','QA7','QA8','QF1','QF2','QF2c','QF2a','QF5',
                                                                                       'QF6','QF7','QF8','QF9','QF10','QX5','QX12')
                                                                                        then a.Answers END
FROM [SplitOut] a
INNER join [DimResponder] b on a.responseid = b.ResponseID and a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
INNER join Question_List c on a.qid = c.qid
left outer JOIN Data_Map datamap ON a.QID = datamap.QID and a.answers = datamap.[answer code]
left outer join DimProduct d on a.ProductID = d.ProductTypeCode and a.ProjectID = d.ProjectID
left outer join DimAttribute e on e.projectid = 0 and a.AttributeID = e.AttributeCode
left outer join Q2AnswerData f on a.QID = f.QID and a.Answers = f.AnswerCode and a.AttributeID = f.VariableID
where a.columnNames not like '%open%' and a.ColumnNames not like '%seg%' and a.columnnames not like '%rot%' and a.Answers not like ''and datamap.Project not in ('Project 0') and a.ProjectID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: If you comment out the INSERT, how long does just the SELECT take?

Comment: Probably going to need an execution plan on this one.

Comment: With Jacob H. Your select should be doing the majority of the work, and to improve that the execution plan is the best place to start looking.

Comment: I'm willing to make a bet that the select statement is the cause of the problem- get rid of that distinct and find a better way/real reason why there are duplicates. Ditch the string LIKE operations too, and look to cut out some of those joins. Consider deleting rows from splitout that do not match the where clause

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien I dint run it with an execution plan with the query but I know it says TableScan at Splitout is 84% when I look at the estimated

Comment: The other thing is to speak to your Dba and describe the massive insert ops you're looking to do; it requires resources, transaction logging, undo space etc. You might do better batching this stuff rather than trying to do millions of rows in one hit

Comment: @TabAlleman So the thing is this exact same query with like instead of not like in the last line of the code takes like 4 mins not sure why it takes so long when I add not like

Comment: @CaiusJard Will try to implement some from your first comment, could you elaborate more on the second comment please ?

Comment: The other thing you could try is to use your `SELECT` query to place the data in a temp table and then insert from the temp table. It may be running the whole query on each row as it tries to insert.

Comment: Why are you using not like instead of <>?

Comment: You have some WHERE clauses that look for NOT LIKE '%' which will require your script to go over your entire table multiple times. You could save a lot of time by putting all your subresults in multiple temp table until it's polished enough to the point of just straight INSERT.  If you can avoid it, don't use NOT LIKE and LIKE in your WHERE Clause. Find something more defined.

Comment: @vap0991 Why does the comment addressed to me have nothing to do with the question I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure columns in the ON clauses are indexed.

Just looking at the SQL and not having the table counts and explain plan, here's something to try.  Use a subquery for the SPLITOUT table.  You  say that table has 30,000,000 rows.  Most of your where clause qualifiers are against the SPLITOUT table, so I'm using a subquery to reduce the number of rows joined to it.  The way it's coded in your version, SPLITOUT will possibly be joined to the other tables before the where clause is applied.  I agree with the comments that like clauses are bad.  They don't use an index so you're most likely table scanning your 30,000,000 row table.

I also made the call to DATAMAP a subquery because it's a left join with a qualifier in the where clause.  If there's no row, the qualifier will fail when you may have wanted it to succeed.

Run the subquery on SPLITOUT by itself.  Tune it first. Create a composite index on splitout.projectID, answers, and columnNames.  If the optimizer uses it for projectID, the likes on columnNames may be index scanned.  Once the SPLITOUT subquery is tuned, add the other joins in one at a time.

Try to remove the distinct with cleaner joins.  The optimizer has to sort to do a distinct which is costly.

Don't use like and in when you don't need to.  Use = and not when possible.

I wouldn't use cross join for a query such as this.

```
insert into DimQuestion (ResponderKey, ProjectID, qid, Question,     QuestionType,AttributeID, Attribute, ProductID, ProductCode, ProductName, AnswerCode, AnswerLabel)
SELECT  distinct  RKey
         ,a.ProID
         ,a.qid
         ,c.QID + ' - ' + c.[Ql] as Question
         ,c.[Type] as QType
         ,a.AttributeID
         ,e.Attribute
         ,a.ProductID
         ,d.ProductCode
         ,d.ProductName
         ,a.Answers
         ,'AnswerLabel' = case when a.qid = 'Q2' then f.AnswerLabel
                               when a.qid not in ('Q2','QA','QA1','QA2','QA5','QA6','QA7','QA8','QF1','QF2','QF2c','QF2a','QF5',
                                                  'QF6','QF7','QF8','QF9','QF10','QX5','QX12') 
                                                   then datamap.[Answer Label]
                               when a.qid in ('QA','QA1','QA2','QA5','QA6','QA7','QA8','QF1','QF2','QF2c','QF2a','QF5',
                                              'QF6','QF7','QF8','QF9','QF10','QX5','QX12')
                                                  then a.Answers
                          end
FROM (select a.responseID, a.ProjectID, a.ProID, a.qid, a.AttributeID, a.ProductID, a.Answers 
  from [SplitOut]
  where a.ProjectID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
        and a.Answers <> ''  -- don't use like when equality or inequality will work, note not and <> do not use the index
        and a.columnNames not like '%open%' and a.ColumnNames not like '%seg%' and a.columnnames not like '%rot%'  -- very bad, won't use index, consider creating a category or codes column to identify these values.
 ) a
 inner join [DimResponder] b on a.responseid = b.ResponseID and a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID
 inner join Question_List c on a.qid = c.qid
 left outer join (select quid, [Answer Code] ,[Answer Label] from datamap     where datamap.Project <> 'Project 0') datamap ON a.QID = datamap.QID and a.answers = datamap.[answer code]
 left outer join DimProduct d on a.ProductID = d.ProductTypeCode and a.ProjectID = d.ProjectID
 left outer join DimAttribute e on e.projectid = 0 and a.AttributeID = e.AttributeCode
 left outer join Q2AnswerData f on a.QID = f.QID and a.Answers = f.AnswerCode and a.AttributeID = f.VariableID
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner and outer joins tend to be expensive (used to do a lot of SQL years ago and they were then).  You may be able to do it as several insert statements and it may be a lot faster, expecialy if you can reduce/get rid on inner/outer joins.

Also maybe making some temp tables will help, pre processing some of the data.

Also prociding a list of indexed will realy help.  Indexes can make the diference wetween minutes and houres,